# Attach handle on every onhide method of bootstrap3-dialog

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I'm using `bootstrap3-dialog` library from https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/
The problem is, everytime the dialog shows (alert, confirm or custom dialog), the body's scrollbar is gone and never come back when dialog closed. I could add this line on every dialog's `onhide` property, but that would be time consuming:

```
$('body').css('overflow','scroll')
```

Is there any other way to trigger that function every time the modal closes?

Answer (score 1):

I was going through the code of bootstrap modal and they have this:

```
resetScrollbar: function() {
        var openedDialogs = this.getGlobalOpenedDialogs();
        if (openedDialogs.length === 0) {
            this.$body.css('padding-right', BootstrapDialogModal.ORIGINAL_BODY_PADDING);
        }
    },
```

Which is called on:

```
hideModal: function() {
        this.$element.hide();
        this.backdrop($.proxy(function() {
            var openedDialogs = this.getGlobalOpenedDialogs();
            if (openedDialogs.length === 0) {
                this.$body.removeClass('modal-open');
            }
            this.resetAdjustments();
            this.resetScrollbar();
            this.$element.trigger('hidden.bs.modal');
        }, this));
    }
```

I can't seem to figure out what would cause this code to not bring the scrollbar back. It seems to be working fine on their website.

If you are comfortable, I would suggest debugging the hideModal function of the api itself and figure out why it is not working and maybe put the above css snippet in there as a work around.

Or maybe post your code on plunkr, jsfiddle so we can look at what is going on.